# Search by date not working in list search box

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2016, date

So I have a list which contain a date column named `my_date`. My site's locale in regional setting is set to English (United Kingdom) so date is displayed as DD/MM/YYYY and time zone is UTC + 3

I ran full crawl which completed successfully. Now when I try to search by date in the search box which you see inside a list then no result is displayed. I have tried different formats for e.g. DD/MM/YYYY, MM/DD/YYYY, YYYY-MM-DD but no luck. But when I search by date from the search box which is shown on top right corner of site then results are displayed. You know the one from where you can do site wide search.

Searching by any other column such as text or number shows result. Only search by date is not working.
In short, search by date inside list search box, no result. Search by date from site wide search box, results are displayed.

I even created new managed property called "mydate" and mapped it to crawled properties "ows_my_date" and "ows_q_date_my_date" then did full crawl again but same issue.

By the way this was working a few days ago and later I reset index and did full crawl and since then it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the time in UTC time zone for searching the item.

As we all know that SharePoint stores the date in UTC time zone in database, so after crawling the database, the UTC value will be indexed, so we need to search with UTC date value.

Similar issue post for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/5674965a-ec65-4a92-925d-8fe470195248/sharepoint-2013-custom-date-field-not-able-to-search-on-library-level-quotfind-in-filesquot?forum=sharepointgeneral

If the issue still exists, make sure the managed property is searchable, start a full crawl again.